# Four Partitions - But Which One Holds the Operating System?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, laptop, oem

How do I definitively identify which of the four partitions on my 14.04.5 laptop holds the OS? The laptop came with just 14.04.5 installed by the OEM. My understanding is that a Ubuntu OS resides in its own dedicated partition, with all the user-created files stored in a separate partition.

Terminal command "lsblk" identifies the 7.8GB sda4 partition as [SWAP] but is silent on the 500MB sda1, 3GB sda2 and the 455GB sda3 partitions. The hard drive is 500GB.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 465.8G 0 disk 
├─sda1 8:1 0 500M 0 part 
├─sda2 8:2 0 3G 0 part 
├─sda3 8:3 0 454.5G 0 part 
└─sda4 8:4 0 7.8G 0 part [SWAP]
```

Comment: When you run lsblk, is your version showing the mount points? If so the / (root) is the operating system. If configured with a separate /home partition then that would also be shown. Post your lsblk.

Comment: Here you go: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda      8:0    0  465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0      3G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  454.5G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0    7.8G  0 part [SWAP]

Comment: Live installer (ubuntu@ubuntu)  does not show mount points of your install.  If working from live installer, not your install: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred - I'm working from the restored-to-factory-state OS on the hard drive (not a live-USB/CD) after the OS was trashed when I attempted a global software update.  Seems the OS is in the huge sda3 partition (455GB) rather than in its own on this brand-new Dell Inspiron 15-3552.  Not what I expected.

Comment: You have icons for various edits and use the code icon {} after highlighting the code. I copied your lsblk but it lost the tabs/spaces for alignment with heading.

Answer (score 0):

the `df` command shows all mounted devices and their mount points:

```
$ df 
Dateisystem    1K-Blöcke Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev             1003044       0   1003044    0% /dev
tmpfs             204848    8816    196032    5% /run
/dev/sda1        8170180 8102904         0  100% /
tmpfs            1024228   26292    997936    3% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1024228       0   1024228    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs                100       0       100    0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs             204848      20    204828    1% /run/user/1000
```

the system partition is moutet on `/` so you get that with the command:

```
$ df /
Dateisystem    1K-Blöcke Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda1        8170180 8102904         0  100% /
```

Comment: Using the df command reveals that the OS is in the 455GB sda3 partition on this Dell laptop. Is that normal? I'd read/been told that the OS would normally be in its own 7-25GB sized partition.  Incidentally how does one "pretty-up" Terminal output as in the answer and not (yet) in my question?

Comment: incidentally, lsblk is an alternative way to see the blk device + partitioning + moutpoints.